# Relation R=2K (two dimensions)

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm looking for a proof of the relation shown above, where $R$ is the scalar curvature and $K$ the gaussian curvature in two dimensions. I've ended up in the following post:

[Physics Exchange Post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/477949/proof-that-the-scalar-curvature-of-a-two-dimensional-space-can-be-expressed-by-o)

Looking at @Prahar 's answer, is the following relation valid?

$$K=\frac{R^1_{212}}{g_{22}}$$

If not, what would be a valid proof of $R=2K$?

Thank you in advance,

A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the curvature tensor of $(M^n,g)$ has the form $$R(X,Y)Z = K(\langle Y,Z\rangle X - \langle X,Z\rangle Y)$$for some function $K\colon M \to \Bbb R$ (which is necessarily constant if $n \geq 3$ -- this is called Schur's Theorem), we trace both sides on the variable $X$ to obtain $${\rm Ric}(Y,Z) = K(n\langle Y,Z\rangle - \langle Y,Z\rangle) = (n-1)K\langle Y,Z\rangle.$$Now take the $g$-trace on the variables $Y$ and $Z$ to obtain $${\rm s} = n(n-1)K,$$where ${\rm s}$ is the scalar curvature. For $n=2$, the curvature tensor of $(M^2,g)$ has the above form, where $K$ is its Gaussian curvature. Thus ${\rm s} = 2K$ in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ivo.